# MVC webservice XML fields not captured

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have created an MVC webservice. The service accepts an httppost with an XML file that represents a ticket.
Not all the XML fields are transfered to the a ticket object instance.
However, when I change the order of the nodes in the XML file, other fields are captured.
But I cannot find any logic in this.

TicketController:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace Webservice.Controllers
{
    public class TicketController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<string> Add(Ticket ticket)
        {
            return await Handler.CreateTicketAsync(ticket);
        }
    }
}
```

"Ticket" class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
namespace Eurosys.Freshdesk.Webservice.Models
{
    [DataContract]
    public class Ticket
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "companyid")]
        public string CompanyId { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "contactname")]
        public string ContactName { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "contactphone")]
        public string ContactPhone { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "contactmobile")]
        public string ContactMobile { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "priority")]
        public int Priority { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "subject")]
        public string Subject { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "long_description")]
        public string LongDescription { get; set; }
    }
}
```

my XML file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<Ticket xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Webservice.Models">
  <id>1</id>
  <companyid>2</companyid>  
  <email>nomail@gmail.com</email>
  <contactname>John Doe</contactname>   
  <contactphone>3</contactphone>
  <priority>1</priority>
  <subject>testsubject</subject>   
  <long_description>testdescription</long_description>
</Ticket>
```

The fields Id, Priority and Subject are updated in the Ticket-object. All other fields are null

When I change the order in the XML file eg. (so email before id):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<Ticket xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Webservice.Models">
  <email>nomail@gmail.com</email>
  <id>1</id>
  <companyid>2</companyid>  
  <contactname>John Doe</contactname>   
  <contactphone>3</contactphone>
  <priority>1</priority>
  <subject>testsubject</subject>   
  <long_description>testdescription</long_description>
</Ticket>
```

Ticket.Id, Priority and LongDescription are filled, as is Ticket.Email which is filled now too.

When I change the order in the XML file eg. (so subject before id):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<Ticket xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Webservice.Models">
  <email>nomail@gmail.com</email>
  <subject>testsubject</subject>   
  <id>1</id>
  <companyid>2</companyid>  
  <contactname>John Doe</contactname>   
  <contactphone>3</contactphone>
  <priority>1</priority>
  <long_description>testdescription</long_description>
</Ticket>
```

Now: ticket.Email and ticket.Subject are filled, but ticket.Longdescription and ticket.Priority not any more

What is the logic? Why are not all ticket-fields filled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fields in the XML request must be in alphabetical order.